# c# Append XDocument Before Saving to File

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm a beginning c# learner and am trying to use LINQ to save an XML file with my application's configuration data.

I want the structure to look like this when the file is finished:

```
<UABA>
  <Configure_Tab>
    <Actions_List>
      <ListItem_1 Position_X="1080" Position_Y="1920" RGB="255,255,255" Is_Colour="TRUE" Target="F1" Button="1" />
      <ListItem_2 Position_X="1080" Position_Y="1920" RGB="255,255,255" Is_Colour="TRUE" Target="F1" Button="1" />
      <ListItem_3 Position_X="1080" Position_Y="1920" RGB="255,255,255" Is_Colour="TRUE" Target="F1" Button="1" />
      <ListItem_4 Position_X="1080" Position_Y="1920" RGB="255,255,255" Is_Colour="TRUE" Target="F1" Button="1" />
    </Actions_List>
  </Configure_Tab>
</UABA>
```

I am reading my data from a ListView and right now my code looks like this:

```
public static void SaveConfiguration(ListViewItemCollection items)
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("UABA",
                                       new XElement("Configure_Tab",
                                           new XElement("Actions_List",
                                           new XElement("ListItem_1", 
                                           new XAttribute("Position_X", "1080"),
                                           new XAttribute("Position_Y","1920"),
                                           new XAttribute("RGB", "255,255,255"),
                                           new XAttribute("Is_Colour", "TRUE"),
                                           new XAttribute("Target", "F1"),
                                           new XAttribute("Button", "1"))))));
    doc.Save("MySettings.xml");
}
```

ListItem_1 will need to be incremented (e.g., ListItem_2, ListItem_3, etc.) for each new line of the ListView and the attributes above will need to be read from the SubItems for the current line. I do know that I could use a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{  
    for (int j = 1; j < items[i].SubItems.Count; j++)
    {

    }
 }
```

Where "i" is the current ListView line and "j" is the SubItem count, but I'm not sure how to append the current XDocument before writing to the file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So after more researching and playing with things, I've found the answer to my own question.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using static System.Windows.Forms.ListView;

public static void SaveConfiguration(ListViewItemCollection items)
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("UABA",
    new XElement("Configure_Tab",
    new XElement("Actions_List"))));

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Add(new XElement("ListItem_" + i, items[i].Checked));

        for (int j = 0; j < items[i].SubItems.Count; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
                doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_" + i).Add(new XAttribute("Position_X", items[i].SubItems[j].Text));
            if (j == 1)
                doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_" + i).Add(new XAttribute("Position_Y", items[i].SubItems[j].Text));
            if (j == 2)
                doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_" + i).Add(new XAttribute("RGB", items[i].SubItems[j].Text));
            if (j == 3)
                doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_" + i).Add(new XAttribute("Is_Colour", items[i].SubItems[j].Text));
            if (j == 4)
                doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_" + i).Add(new XAttribute("Target", items[i].SubItems[j].Text));
            if (j == 5)
                doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_" + i).Add(new XAttribute("Press_Button", items[i].SubItems[j].Text));
        }
    }

    doc.Save("MySettings.xml");
}
```

Comment: Xml of this kind: `ListItem_{N}` - hard to parse and process. Better add `Id` or `Index` attribute.

Comment: What do you mean hard to parse? Because it's a string instead of an integer?